# Facebook SDK: How to i get the photo properties after posting an image?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i just made a photo upload via the Facebook SDK to my personal wall.
When i trace the "request:didLoad" method, i get only the "id" and "post_id" back.
Here are all my necessary methods:

```
-(void) postPhoto:(UIButton*)button{
    UIImage *uploadImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage"];    
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   uploadImage, @"source", 
                                   @"test caption", @"message",             
                                   nil];

    [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:(id)self];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{
    NSLog(@"Request didLoad: %@", result);
}
```

Output:

> Request didLoad: {
>       id = 3273804256400;
>       "post_id" = "1608527600_3273799016300"; }

So, i´m wondering why there are not more information about the [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) ?
I thought i get back all kinds of the Photo fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get further information about the photo, you will need to perform another request.  If you make a graph request for the id, you will get the information.  For example, you could call https://graph.facebook.com/3273804256400 and receive info like people tagged in the photo, likes, comments, etc.

Facebook assumes that if you posted the photo you don't need to know info about it, which is why they only give you the id and post_id.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem.
When you get an additional facebook permission, "user_photos", you could get photo URL.